# How to display Static Custom Cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I am trying to create some static table view cells to store my contents. I set up my nib file as seen in the picture:

[image: Custom Table Cell][image]

In essence, I only have one static cell, containing a map view and a label.

Next I configure my Xcode files as follows:

Header:

```
@interface CarParkDetailViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UITableViewCell *infoCell;
    MKMapView *detailMapView;
    UILabel *addressLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *infoCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *detailMapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    return infoCell;
}
```

The code above doesn't work. (Didn't seem right in the first place). I am getting the following error

> `***` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Can anyone advise me on what the correct approach is in displaying my `infoCell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a custom cell in a view controller, which  is not possible. Use IB to create a custom cell and design your UI there. Then use the following code in your cellForRowAtIndex method:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nibObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
            cell = (CustomCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Krishnan, thanks for your response. What if I need each role to be of a different design? Can I use this approach? Actually I was trying to follow the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html. under the 'The Technique for Static Row Content' section. But I must be missing something here. Any advise is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: This is the first time I am seeing this approach. I will see it and respond.

Comment: I believe you must be missing the IB connections between your cell in controller and XIb file. I developed a similar app and tested. I had no problems. And you can also try to debug and see if the value of infoCell is nil or has some values.

Comment: Hi Krishnan, ok I will test it out. In the meantime can you take a look at the additional screenshot I added in my original question? I linked my infoCell to the file owner. Is that sufficient? Thanks

Comment: Hi Krishnan, do you mind sharing with me what you did in your test app? I debugged and the cell indeed returned me a null value. But I checked that all my connections have already been hooked up...